# finding highest value in hash

Tags: perl, hash

I have a hash with 5 keys, each of these keys have 5 values

```
foreach $a(@mass){
   if($a=~some regex){
       @value=($1,$2,$3,$4,$5);
       $hash{"keysname$c"}="@value";
       c++;
    }
}
```

Each scalar is a value of different parameters , I have to determinate the highest value of the first array for the all keys in hash

Edit:

Code must compare first value of key1 with first value of key2, key3...key5 and print the highest one

Comment: Your example doesn't show five keys, nor array as hash value.

Comment: This code is in the loop which collects values from regexpt and creates array with those collected values, so my loop creates 5 keys with 5 values in the %hash

Comment: This code does not. It creates one key, with a string as value.

Comment: The actual code is $hash{"name$c"}="@value"; c++;.. So it does

Comment: Yes, now it does, but only because you changed it. `"@value"` is still not an array, though, it is a string. If you assigned `\@value` then it would be an array, but then you would need to use a lexically scoped array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will print max value for structure like

```
my %hash = ( k1 => [6,4,1], k2 => [16,14,11] );

use List::Util qw(max);

# longest array
my $n = max map $#$_, values %hash;

for my $i (0 .. $n) {

  my $max = max map $_->[$i], values %hash;
  print "max value on position $i is $max\n";
}
```

and for strings,

```
my %hash = ( k1 => "6 4 1", k2 => "16 14 11" );

use List::Util qw(max);

# longest array
my $n = max map $#{[ split ]}, values %hash;

for my $i (0 .. $n) {

  my $max = max map [split]->[$i], values %hash;
  print "max value on position $i is $max\n";
}
```

Comment: Your code prints the highest value for each key, I need a code that will compare the values of key1->value1 with key2->value2 and print the highest one

Comment: Ok, what about continuously check of other 4 values?

Comment: Ok, but I need to check first value of the key1 with the fist value of key2, and the second value of key1 with the second value of value 2, as I said, every value is a different parameter and they must be compared with each other

Comment: Oh yes, its working! But i have one more little problem, my regex return numbers in string, how to convert it to int to be able to use your code?

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question correctly (and it's a little unclear) then I think you want something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;
use List::Util 'max';

my (@data, @max);

while (<DATA>) {
  chomp;
  push @data, [split];
}

for my $i (0 .. $#{$data[0]}) {
  push @max, max map { $_->[$i] } @data;
}

say "@max";

__DATA__
93 3 26 87 7
66 96 46 77 42
26 3 71 64 91
31 27 14 40 86
82 72 71 34 7
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
    map {push @temp, @{$_}} values %hash;
    @desc_sorted= sort {$b <=> $a} @temp;
    print $desc_sorted[0],"\n";
```

map will consolidate all lists to a single list and sort will sort that consolidated array in descending order.